# Can I run some jobs conditionally in github workflow, e.g only on specific trigger?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, cd

I have workflow with Build and Publish jobs.

I would like to run Build job on push and pullrequest triggers, but Publish only on push. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  Build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      [...]

  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}
    steps:
      [...]
```

The worflow will run on both `push` and `pull_request` events. Since the `Build` job doesn't have any `if` statement or dependencies it will always run. `Publish` on the other hand will only run if the event that triggered the worflow is a `push`.

I am guessing here, but if both jobs have to run sequentially, one after the other, you should use this form instead:

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Build
        run: [...]

      - name: Publish
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}
        run: [...]
```

Jobs are running independently on different machines. You will need special actions to pass files around. By using **steps in a same job**, you ensure that both steps run sequentially and that files created by the first step are available to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are separate `push` and `pull_request` events for the `on:` directive that will trigger a workflow run.

So, your `build.yml` workflow would have

```yaml
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
```

which would trigger it on push and pull requests.

Your `publish.yml` workflow would have

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches
      - master
```

which would trigger only on push.

You can read more about trigger setup [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on).